# C++ Passing a set of objects to a member functions of abstract class

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, abstract, pure-virtual

I would like to pass objects to a member functions of class and execute some functions from within it. When I do this using the *myCars pointers, everything works fine. But when I try to pass this to do the same for a pure virtual class, the program returns error (see Solution A). I've got a temporary solution (see Solution B), but it does not seem right to me. Any idea to fix it?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"
#include "veicles.h"
#include "traffic.h"

int main(){

        int number = 3;
        Car *myCars = new Car[number];

        Traffic mtc;
        mtc.import(myCars, number);

        Veicles *myVeicles = new Car[number];

//      Solution A
//      Traffic mtvA;
//      mtvA.import(myVeicles, number);

//      Solution B
        std::cout << "\nsolution B\n";
        Traffic mtvB;
        mtvB.import(&myVeicles, number);

        delete[] myCars;
        delete[] myVeicles;

        return 0;
}
```

car.h

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include "veicles.h"

class Car : public Veicles{
public:
    void move();

};

#endif
```

car.cpp

```
#include "car.h"

void Car::move(){

        std::cout << "the car is moving\n";
}
```

traffic.h

```
#ifndef TRAFFIC_H
#define TRAFFIC_H

#include "car.h"

class Traffic{
public:

    void import(Car p[], int number);
    void import(Veicles *v[], int number);
private:

    Veicles *vc;

};

#endif
```

traffic.cpp

```
#include "traffic.h"
#include "car.h"

void Traffic::import(Car p[], int number){

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
                p[i].move();
        }
} 

void Traffic::import(Veicles *v[], int number){

        vc = *v; 
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
               // vc -> move();
               vc[i].move(); //  EDIT: R Sahu sugestion
        }
}
```

veicles.h

```
#ifndef VEICLES_H
#define VEICLES_H

class Veicles{
public:

    virtual void move() = 0;
};

#endif
```

veicles.cpp

```
#include "veicles.h"

// some stuffs to do latter..
```

makefile

```
all:    clean car veicles traffic main
        g++ car.o traffic.o main.o -o main.out
run:
        ./main.out

car:    car.h
        g++ -c car.cpp -o car.o

veicles: car.h veicles.h
        g++ -c veicles.cpp -o veicles.o

traffic: traffic.h car.h
        g++ -c traffic.cpp -o traffic.o


main: traffic.h car.h
        g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o

clean:
        rm -f *.o
        rm -f *.gch
```

Comment: Solution A: From main function, it seems like you're passing a pointer to an array of `Cars` (but pointer has type `Veicles`). Since pointer has type `Veicles`, the abstract function from `class Veicles` gets called. And since it's an abstract virtual function... a wild error spawns.

Comment: Be careful with terminology. You don't pass objects to classes. You pass objects to **member functions** of classes.

Comment: @PeteBecker, I changed the title. Thank you.

Comment: The code makes very little sense. This is not how you use inheritance in C++. `Veicles *myVeicles = new Car[number];` is a very common error that compilers unfortunately don't catch. You cannot do this (you'll find it out the hard way as soon as you start adding data to your Car class). Is this an assignment?

Comment: @n.m. This is a simplification of another project that I did in order to explain the problem. Unfortunately I should choose another function to be shared with the Car class, because every vehicle can move in the same way. But if you substitute the function "load_material ()" for example, it may make more sense. Only trucks (and they are vehicles as well) will be able to accomplish this task, but some have dump, others carry containers and will do so in different ways.

Comment: `Veicles *myVeicles = new Car[number];` is wrong regardless of whether your code is real or a simplification of something real. So either (1) you are doing the wrong thing in your real code (and you should understand the error and fix it), or (2) you are not representing your real code adequately (and the entire discussion is meaningless).

Comment: In a correctly designed OO program there should be no need in two nearly identical versions of `Traffic::import`. I'm not sure if your two versions come from you not fully understanding object orientation in general, or just from not understanding of how arrays work in presence of inheritance.

Comment: @n.m. For me Car *myCars = new Car [number] makes sense, but I had never tried anything like Veicles *myVeicles = new Car [number]. Honestly, I do not remember where I've seen this before. Yes, I used Traffic :: import for the same purpose, but it's because I needed a way to pass these objects to the Traffic class. It was just for testing. Anyway, I'm going to look for a more suitable solution to create objects, capable of performing the same function in different ways. Thank you.

Comment: @n.m. I found something very close to what I did. The difference is that I used an array. See the latest example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

Comment: That's right, a triangle is a polygon, but an array of triangles is **not** an array of polygons (or at least C++ doesn't let you treat it this way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  void import(Car p[], int number);
```

is the same as

```
  void import(Car* p, int number);
```

You may not call it with an argument of type `Vehicle*` since a base class pointer cannot be automatically converted to derived class pointer.

Imagine you had:

```
class Truck : public Veicles{
 ...
};
```

and

```
Veicles *myVeicles = new Truck[number];
```

If the compiler let you call that function, you would suddenly able to use a `Truck` where a `Car` was expected. That would lead to disaster.

---

The following function works

```
void Traffic::import(Veicles *v[], int number){
   vc = *v; 
   for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
      vc -> move();
   }
}
```

However, please note that you are not using `i` to access the elements of `vc`. You are calling `move()` on the first object only.

The following would be a problem.

```
void Traffic::import(Veicles *v[], int number){
   vc = *v; 
   for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
      vc[i].move();
   }
}
```

The reason for that is you may not treat an array of derived class objects as an array of base class objects.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution replacing "vc -> move ()" with "vc [i] .move ()" is better. In addition I suspect that creating a "vc" pointer of the class Veicles, as I created it does not seem correct. I will look for software architecture topics to try to avoid this mess.